# How can I pass function parameters to an erb view with sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb

I currently have this:

```
get '/myapp/get/:func' do
    erb :server, :locals => {:func => params[:func]}
end
```

And then in my server.erb file I have this:

```
if (func == "myFunc1")
    myFunc1
elsif (func == "myFunc2")
    myFunc2
etc...
```

The ruby functions called in server.erb are defined.

Now I want to define a new function, and I want to pass a variable to it. So what I want in my server.erb is this:

```
def myNewFunc(param1)
   # do stuff with param1
end
```

How do I pass `param1` to sinatra?

Note: The parameter I want to pass in is just an integer between 0 and 6.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to pass `params` as locals, you can se them anywhere in your code – if that is what you mean.

Comment: Not exactly. I have three files: myapp.rb, a ruby file with sinatra stuff in it; server.erb, the erb file with ruby methods; and myapp.js, the javascript that runs my app. Currently, none of the methods in server.erb accept any arguments, so I need only pass the name of the method to sinatra. But now I want to make a method that does take arguments, and I'm unsure how to get those arguments from the javascript to the erb file.